# How to concatenate equal sign and a variable such that result is usable in a mysql query of the type shown below?

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a mysql query based on several variables being posted from a bootstrap 4 form.  I am struck at how to concatenate one of the posted variable 'prof' so as to use it for the query in two different scenarios: (1) When the user makes no choice and a NULL value is posted (2) When the user selects a particular profession and a specific value is posted. I need to concatenate the variable in a manner that I get the result of the type: = 'P01' and not just = P01 as it won't work in the mysql query:  I am posting part of the code to show how I am handling the posted variable and the query itself. The query also includes some of the variables that i have been able to use successfully.

```
if(isset($_POST['prof_match']) && ($_POST['prof_match']) != 'NULL') {
  $choice_prof = "= " . ($_POST['prof_match']); // Example P01 is Accountant
}else {
  $choice_prof = 'IN(SELECT prof FROM profiles)';
}

// The query is as follows:

SELECT * 
FROM profiles 
WHERE age $choice_age 
AND height $choice_ht 
AND edn $choice_edn 
AND prof $choice_prof;
```

The resulting string I get from the $choice_prof is quote = A01 unquote while what i need is quote = 'P01' unquote.

English not being my first language please ignore the syntax and grammatical mistakes.  Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: if you get `A01` this means you entered `A01`

Comment: i would suggest that you read what a [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is and [How you can prevent a SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I would be using pdo binding to prevent sql injection but right now i am struck at how to concatenate the variable to be used in the query such that i don't have to put equal sign as the same query would be using the alternative response using IN(SELECT prof FROM profiles) syntax that doesn't use = sign. Thanks for your caution @ Raymond Nijland

Comment: Fair enough but most likely you want to rewrite `SELECT .. WHERE .. IN(...)` into using a join as `IN(SELECT ..)` tends to optimize bad if profiles is a "huge" table.

Comment: Maybe someone will hate me for the suggestion, but you could leverage the form `IN (?)`, instead of `= ?` to make the two queries more similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very straight forward to use php variable and generate an sql string.

If you need quotation marks around your variable yo put them in your sql string like so:

```
$sql = "select * from table where some_column = '$variable'";
```

In your case, just put them in your string like this:

```
if ( !empty($_POST['prof_match']) ) {
    $choice_prof = " = ' " . $_POST['prof_match'] . "'";
} else {
    $choice_prof = 'IN(SELECT prof FROM profiles)';
}

SELECT * 
    FROM profiles 
WHERE 
    age $choice_age AND 
    height $choice_ht AND 
    edn $choice_edn AND 
    prof $choice_prof;
```

For the `empty()` function refer to [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: Mind the SQL injections, as hackers/crackers/scriptkiddies would love to see this code used.

Comment: ^ Yes, As you have mentioned in your comment above as well. Thanks

Comment: @Bsienn Thanks  a lot.  The second line of the code above is how i needed to concatenate my variables to be used in my query.  And thanks to those who cautioned to use PDO prepared statement, I would exactly be doing that.  Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 2):

As a means to kill 2 birds (solving your problem and sanitising your inputs) with one stone (using a prepared statement). You can do:

```
$parameters = [ $age, $height, $edn ]; //Actual values here, not values with condition
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE age = ? AND height = ? AND edn = ? AND prof';
if(isset($_POST['prof_match']) && ($_POST['prof_match']) != 'NULL') {     
  $parameters[] = $_POST['prof_match'];
  $sql .= '= ?';
}else {
  $sql .= ' IN(SELECT prof FROM profiles)';
}
```

You can then execute this as a prepared statement.

PDO example:

```php
$statement = $pdoObject->prepare($sql);
$result = $statement->execute($parameters);
```

It is similar in MySQLi as well.

Comment: The option where it uses `IN(SELECT prof FROM profiles)` is used seems excessive.

Comment: also to add to @NigelRen 's comment most likely you want to rewrite `SELECT .. WHERE ,, IN(...)` into using a join as `IN(SELECT ..)` tends to optimize bad if profiles is a "huge" table.

Comment: @NigelRen I really didn't read that part that much. Just copy-pasted from the question. That part as it's written is actually not necessary but I'll keep it because (I'm assuming) OP wants it there (for some reason)